# Displaying data in Android app with php backend

Tags: php, android

I have question about structuring applications. I'm making, for example, a Twitter-like app. This application must make a query on a url (it's done by asynctask) and gets a reply (it can be Json, serialized array, or even html).

In next step app outputs data. For example, latest news. I don't know in which ways it can be done. I tried  to make it with html data from the backend and viewing it through the web-view, then I added click listener on links. With this I can control the app and navigate. After that I turned on JavaScript in web-view and can control the DOM. In the web-view, drawing images is easier.

Am I going in right direction or do I need to use something like list-view to output? And what future problems may there be using this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, your question is very confused, but I'll try to ask. As you sayed you have 2 alternatives, one is to built your interface natively and retrieve the data from a Web Service via an asyncTask, the other is to use a WebView.

Both approach are valid, but think that is you use a WebView you are building an non-native application (in fact is an hybrid application) so you need to simulate the native behaviour (this can cause you problems in the future)

I prefer to use a WS and build the interface with native widgets,  for comunication you can use JSON.

If you prefer to use a WebView, I recommend you to use a framework like [Sencha](http://www.sencha.com/) or [phonegap](http://phonegap.com/)

Comment: thanks for your answer. So using webview to output and "design" content it is normal practice ?

Comment: Yes, take a look to phonegap for example.